# Pycharm errors that are not python errors

Tags: python, pycharm

I just installed pyCharm(2016.2) community onto my macBook Pro running El Capitan.  I have been using the same version of pyCharm on windows.  I copied a simple program to the mac that runs successfully on windows.  My mac is catching the following as an error.  The error is:

```
 ')' expected
Statement expected, found Py:EQ)
```

The code:

```
print('See no new', end='')
```

similarly with

`print('See','The','Separator', sep='\t')`   on the last parameter

where is does not like the end='' part.  It wants a closing parenthesis.  Windows does not capture this error, and it runs fine in Python 3.5. (My interpreter is set to Python 3.5).  It also runs great on Wing IDE and Geany.

I don't understand the differences as I never made changes to Inspections on either machine.  And, this is not a python error.   I'm ready to immediately abandon PyCharm for another IDE.  But I was really happy with it on Windows.

Thanks to anyone answering this question.

Al

Comment: Well, there is always the possibility that you are calling a windows function on a mac, which will not work. Perhaps try () at the end?

Comment: Are you running the code under Python 2 or 3?